# External Monitors connected via HDMI to USB not working

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

External monitors not working or being recognized in settings > displays when connected via hdmi -> usb adapter or docking station.

Problem discovered after installing and rebooting system updates on 7/18/22. First thought was hardware failure (adapter) so ordered docking station, installed it's drivers but it is not working either. Settings > Displays does not recognize an external monitor is connected.

Troubleshooting:

- Monitor Hardware: Both monitors can work when directly plugged into the HDMI port.
- Docking Station:

  - Both monitors can work connected to dock when booted into Windows.
  - Keyboard and Mouse can work through dock station.
- Confirmed adapter and docking station recognized on the usb bus.
- Driver/Kernel Incompatibility: Attempted this [solution](https://displaylink.org/forum/showpost.php?p=92453&postcount=3) to modify the driver installer but no improvement.
- Booted into previous kernel (v5.13.0-52-generic), uninstalled driver, reinstalled driver, no improvement.
- When connecting the monitor through the docking station it recognizes that a connection has happened, cycles through the inputs and responds with "No Signal"
- Tested all above options in X11 and Wayland modes.

Hardware:

- Dell Inspirion 3593
- Montiors: Acer KB272HL
- USB Adapter: [Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08C24523X)
- Docking Station: Dell D3100

  - Latest Driver: [DisplayLink v5.6](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu)

Software:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Previous Kernel v5.13.0-52-generic
- Upgraded Kernel v5.15.0-41-generic

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu on a USB drive handy?  Preferably same version as what you're using (20.04).  If you booted off of that, everything works ok?

Comment: Tried booting from USB stick (20.04) and that gave the same behavior as listed in post.

Answer (score -1):

Re-did the downgrade kernel to v5.13.0-52-generic, uninstall/reinstall driver process.

I think the first time downgrading the kernel, I accidentally skipped the `sudo apt autoremove` step and therefore not everything was fully removed.